# Is "on the higher side" a meaningful phrase?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idiomatic-language, formal-language

I was documenting a software feature for an internal audience and I wrote:

"...when the character count is on the higher side."

Here, I wanted to mean a case where the number of characters is too many. I was not supposed to give the actual number so I wrote this. To me, "too many" sounds informal in this context. However, people had reservations about the usage of the phrase "on the higher side."

Is this a correct usage? Can it be used in formal settings? Are there any other alternative phrases?

Comment: It would usually be the "flat" form *...is on the **high** side* anyway, but you should note that this usage is both ***vague*** and ***informal***. In any halfway "formal" context, I suggest rephrasing to something more like *...is **relatively high***. Better yet, make sure your context properly defines what "high" means here, so you don't need to include "relatively" to reflect the lack of precision. Then it's just *when the character count is high.*

Comment: Yes, it is a meaningful phrase. However, it doesn't express what you wanted to say -- "higher side" still indicates that the character count is OK. If it's excessive, you need to be specific as possible -- say something like "exceeds the established limit".

Comment: on the higher side/ the lower side are used for numbers. This is an idiomatic usage. But you can also use other adjectives: that is on the expensive side.

Answer (score 0):

The only time you use **the** before a comparative (xxxxx-er) is when you are referring to the xxxx-er of two options. For example, it there were two tables, you could say

> The tall people can sit at **the higher** table.

It would be perfectly acceptable to say:

> ...when the character count is high

It might also be reasonable to say:

> ...when the character count is on the high side

... though this is normally used in the set phrase **a bit on the high side**. Here is an example:

> The price at Rs 15 and 20 of the two volumes respectively is a bit on the high side for individual buyers. - *Journal of industrial and scientific research, 1952*